# How do I take the log of a whole matrix in stata?

Tags: stata

In Stata, how do I take the log of all elements in a matrix?  In matlab you just do log(Matrix).  Apparently things aren't so simple in Stata.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're right that it appears there's no simple way to do that in Stata's main language. But things *are* that simple in [Mata, Stata's matrix programming language](http://stata.com/why-use-stata/introduction-to-mata/index.html), which was introduced in version 9 of Stata in 2005 and behaves more like Matlab:

```
. mata
--------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) -----------------------------
: A=(1, 2 \ 3, 4)

: A
       1   2
    +---------+
  1 |  1   2  |
  2 |  3   4  |
    +---------+

: log(A)
                 1             2
    +-----------------------------+
  1 |            0   .6931471806  |
  2 |  1.098612289   1.386294361  |
    +-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is great, but how do I manipulate a matrix that I created inside of stata but outside of mata.  Mata is not recognizing the matrix I want to manipulate.

Comment: `matamatrix = st_matrix("statamatrix")`

Comment: Thanks, and finally, how do I then call the altered matrix in stata after mata closes?

Comment: `st_matrix("statamatrix",matamatrix)`

Comment: Within Mata: `st_matrix("newstatamatrix", log(A))`

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than implied with `matmap` from SSC. Install using `ssc inst matmap`.

```
. matmap A A, map(ln(@))
```

Here `@` is substituted by each matrix element installed. In the example A A instructs replacing an existing, while A B would create or replace another matrix.